# Как удалить код JavaScript и CSS, блокирующий отображение верхней части страницы

Tags: pagespeed-insights

Доброго времени суток!

Не получается исправить последнее правило от Google Page Speed Insights:

> Удалите код JavaScript и CSS, блокирующий отображение верхней части страницы.
>   Количество блокирующих ресурсов CSS на странице: 1. Они замедляют отображение контента.
>
> Примерно 3 % содержания верхней части страницы можно отобразить, не дожидаясь загрузки указанных далее ресурсов. Попробуйте отложить ее или асинхронно загрузить блокирующие ресурсы либо встроить их особо важные составляющие прямо в код HTML.
>
> Оптимизируйте работу CSS на следующих ресурсах:
>   http://ecoexspert.kz/css/style.css

Попробовал разные способы:

1. перенёс CSS вниз body,
2. вынес стили в HTML документ

А Google Page Speed Insights всё равно ругается, как можно исправить проблему?

[Ссылка на ресурс](http://ecoexspert.kz/).

Answer (score 1):

Установите ссылки на ваши файлы css и js внизу перед закрытым элементом /body. При этом, для валидации примените для линка стилей property=stylesheet, примерно так:

```css
<link rel=stylesheet property=stylesheet href=code/example.css>
```

Поиграйте с установкой [async](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/UseAsync) - только для скриптов js: устанавливайте и смотрите какой результат в браузере. Также я рекомендую вам для ускорения применять сжатие исходного кода с [этим инструментом](https://htmlcompressor.com/compressor/) и сжатие картинок с [этим инструментом](http://optimizilla.com/). Пример async: `<script async src=code/modernizr.custom.53362.js></script>`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Попробовал, не помогло, единственное не разобрался с настройкой асинхронности скриптов. Предложенные инструменты, обязательно попробую.

Comment: Я вижу, что вы не установили property=stylesheet для стилей. Без этого создается ошибка валидации

Comment: Сразу после body вы установили блок стилей css. Перенесите этот блок в head.

Answer (score 0):

На всех js файлах добавьте атрибут defer, а весь css уберите куда подальше вниз. И то и другое надо минифицировать, можно еще и то, и другое вставлять в тело страницы.

Comment: defer добавил, не помогло, остальное делал. Пример кода - <script defer src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> Верно?

Answer (score 0):

Оставьте css сверху, js вниз, defer не ставить если подключается больше 1 файла

Answer (score 0):

Сайт почему-то не доступен...

Вообще данная рекомендация гугла (о 3%) напрямую связана с тем, что внешний css-файл небольшой, поэтому лучше от него отказаться, а все стили перенести прямо в html-код страницы (в секцию HEAD). С точки зрения гугла, лучше потратить чуть больше трафика, чем создавать новое http-соединение. С учетом того, что используется gzip-сжатие для html, то всё довольно логично.